# Forward search with vim-latex and evince

Tags: ubuntu, forward-inverse-search, vim, vim-latex, evince

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic
texlive version: 2019
Vim version: 8.1 , big
Vim Plugin Manager: pathogen
Vim Plugins: vim-latex (LatexSuite)

I had changed the settings in my `tex.vim` file so the default compiler would be `pdflatex` instead of `latex`. After compiling tex files in vim with `\ll` ,  I tried to use forward searching with the command `\ls` in vim. However, that would open an `evince` window (evince is also called 'Document viewer') with the output PDF and two other windows with error messages.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to the 'Help' section of evince and found out about Synctex. [The instructions](https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/synctex-support.html.en) online say that you should install the whole `gedit-plugins`, however my solution involved installing only `gedit-plugin-synctex`. So I ran:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
sudo !!
apt-get install gedit-plugin-synctex
```

Then thanks to [this link](http://blog.wuzzeb.org/posts/2013-05-11-vim-latex-forward-search.html), I was able to find the location of the Synctex files. The gedit plugin files, in general, are located at

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/plugins/
```

There, you should find the Synctex folder, and inside it you should find the file `evince_dbus.py`.You can now continue with the [official instructions](https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/synctex-editors.html.en). I copied the file to the folder `~/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux` because it was in the `$PATH`. To find which folders are in your `$PATH`, you can run `echo $PATH` on the terminal.

Now, you have to add some fixes. Ubuntu 18 does not include the `python` command, and instead the default is `python3`. Also, the `evince_dbus.py` file is written in python3 (you can verify this by looking at the code lines that use `print`. In python3, print is a function so the argument goes in parentheses.), so you can use python3 to run the file. You need to open the file first, which can be done with:

```
vim evince_dbus.py
```

Then, you go to the first line, which is the shebang line, and add a `3` at the end, so `python` will become `python3`. Then, on the line 165, you delete the necessary characters to get:

```
input_file  = sys.argv[3]
path_output  = output_file
path_input   = os.getcwd() + '/' + input_file
```

And that is it.You should now be able to do forward searching with the command `\ls`.